# Excel cell reference isn't returning anything

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I'm trying to grab a value from a cell on Excel, when the 'value' is returned it's empty.

At first I thought it may be because the cell was a reference to another cell so I copied the cells and pasted as values to try it out but still returns nothing.

This is the code that's running

```cs
for(int i = from; i < to; i++)
{
    try
    {
        string cellVal = xlSheet.Cells[$"D{i}"].Value2;
        MessageBox.Show(cellVal, "Program", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error", "Program", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Range` to get a single `Cell`?

Comment: Accidental, was messing with columns earlier.

Comment: Perhaps update your question to the real code then?

Comment: You should use a range to retrieve *all* the cells you want at once. Every call and property access is a cross-process access which means it's *slow*. On the other hand, why use Excel Interop at all? You could use a library like ExcelDataReader to read Excel data, or EPPlus to read and create Excel files without installing Excel